# A reverse VLOOKUP?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to achieve the following in Google Sheets.

Context - these are exported bank statements.

I have a sheet of lookup values (string, category).

| String | Category |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | Cat1 |
| DEF | Cat2 |
| GHI | Cat3 |

I have another sheet of data, in particular 1 column which is Description.

| Description | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| THE ABC SHOP TXN:1234567 | 100 |
| THE ABC SHOP TXN:3456789 | 200 |
| DEFINITELY ANOTHER SHOP REF: 1293891 | 500 |

The strings in the first sheet are to look up against as the Descriptions that contain both static and dynamic identifiers in the same column. In particular I need to assign that row a category based on the description against the sheet of regexes I have constructed so that I can do a pivot table against the data for reporting.

| Description | Amount | Category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| THE ABC SHOP TEXAS TXN:1234567 | 100 | Cat1 |
| THE ABC SHOP DALLAS TXN:3456789 | 200 | Cat1 |
| DEFINITELY ANOTHER SHOP HOUSTON REF: 1293891 | 500 | Cat2 |

Ideally this would also be a ARRAYFORMULA.

I can't use a VLOOKUP because that's only works for a exact match.

I've also tried INDEX/MATCH but that causes issues if I try to put a REGEXMATCH inside the expression as I can't put in a range in the REGEXMATCH.

In a way I guess this is a reversed VLOOKUP but instead of finding a match on a target range, I want to find the row of first value that is contained within the source value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=map(A2:A,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,iferror(+tocol(index(if(search(E2:E,Σ),F2:F,)),3),"--"))))
```

[image]

Comment: Phew! Looks comprehensive and lots of things I've never used before in a formula... will digest and get back you.

Comment: Pretty sick, thanks! Seems to work. I'm aware that the "+" there is to suppress some kind of error, but I'm not exactly sure what it is suppressing. If you could enlighten that would be great, otherwise I'm happy that it works :)

Comment: In a scenario there's more than one category match; its just a shortcut used to restrict the range(output) to top single cell value